# What type of relay should I use to trigger an apartment door buzzer?

Tags: arduino, relay

I'm working on my first hardware project, an SMS web app that will submit (via Arduino) a signal to press the buzzer at my apartment building. As such, my vocabulary might be way off.

That said, I think I need a "relay" to close the circuit at the buzzer and unlock the door.

The project is almost done, except for this last piece. How can I figure out what part to buy? How do I test it so I don't mess up my Arduino? I have a starter's kit but I've never used a multimeter, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a relay with a normal open (NO) contact. You don't have to switch high currents, so a low power relay will do. Nevertheless the Arduino output will probably not be able to drive the relay directly (it wants too much current to activate), so you'll need a transistor to drive it, like this:

[image]

Pick a relay with a coil voltage equal to the voltage you have available (the "+12V" at the top). The diode protects the transistor, and can be a 1N4148 (most common general purpose diode).
The relay contact of course goes parallel to the door-opener switch.

[This](http://be.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Tyco-Electronics-Axicom/1-1393793-2/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs3UE%252bXNiFaVEz7rNZFj7Jwi%252b1eue5qRPE%3d) could be an appropriate relay.
*edit: in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/why-different-coil-power-versions-for-a-relay) Federico notes that there are different coil power versions of that relay. Unless you expect strong vibrations or shock choose the 150mW version.*

[This relay](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=108-98009&DocType=SS&DocLang=EN) may be even better: low coil voltage versions available, like 3V and 5V, and requires very low power.