# Why different coil power versions for a relay?

Tags: relay

[This relay](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Specification+Or+Standard%7F108-98007%7FC%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_SS_108-98007_C.pdf) is available in coil powers of 150mW, 200mW, 400mW and >500mW. Why does Tyco make all these versions? Wouldn't everybody want the least power-demanding version? In other words: what's the advantage of the higher power versions?

Comment: All I can think is a more powerful coil gives faster switching with all the associated benefits of such.

Answer (score 3):

Most relays are offered in just one coil power version, with a choice of coil voltages. This one seems to be an exception. Most of the time you'll want the most power-efficient part. Possible reasons for choosing the higher power version:

1. Vibration and shock resistance. The higher power will pull harder on the contact's anode (the moving part), so it won't open that easy when it vibrates.
2. The stronger pull on the contact's anode will probably also result in a slightly lower contact resistance, but I'm not sure how much difference this will make.

Comment: I have never seen the moving part of the contact referred to as "anode", is this a common denomination? (I guess the fixed part is the "cathode" then)

Answer (score 0):

Glossary & References at end.

Can you please identify the relay model concerned - that link has "issues" for me.

It appears it may be a TE PB286xx series [1]. mW ratings do not match those above but do vary between versions and part numbers in your supplied address are similar.

It is likely that the differences are caused by their having different coil voltages. As seen below, similar relays may come with 3V, 5V, 12V, 24V, ... versions. Practical considerations may make it harder to get the same amount of magnetic flux with different coil voltages. Flux is related to amp.turns (current x coil turns). Double the voltage for the same power and you need to halve the current. This implies twice as many turns and double the resistance. Superficially this appears to all scale linearly. In practice packing arrangements, insulation on windings and between windings etc will mean there isn't a direct relationship.

Also, there may be variants with different contact arrangements and quantities. eg the same "family" may have SPST, SPNO, SPDT, SPDT arrangements. More contacts will require greater flux so more amp-turns. A NC contact may require different flux to an NO one.

Pull in or operate speed will be improved my increasing current. Usually a relay with a diffrent pull in speed would not be considered to be the "same" relay. Where relays with different coil voltages or contact arrangements may be.

Without knowing coil Voltage and current ratings and contact arrangements it is not possible to know if any of the above applies.

These are available in a number of coil voltages.
The available Voltage, current (mA) and resultant milliWatts are

- 3, 22, 66 mW
- 5, 16, 80 mW
- 12, 6.7, 80 mW
- 24, 5.3, 127 mW

Here an increasing mW rating with coil voltage is seen not linear. eg doubling coil voltage from 12 V to 24 V (2:1) changes current mW from 80 to 127 (1.6:1).

- NO = Normally open contact(s) close when operated
- NC = Normally closed contact(s)open when operated.

.

- SPST - single pole single throw = on/off
- DPST - 2 x single contacts
- SPDT - single changeover contact, aka CO
- DPDT - 2 changeover contacts
- [1] http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Selection

Comment: The link is to a PDF document, but opens in Acrobat instead of in my browser. The relay is an Axicom D2n **V23105** (that's Tyco)

Comment: @Russell McMahon: if you manage to open the datasheet (stevenvh spelled out the type) you'll see that the power is independant of voltage. 1)Every power version is available in the different standard voltages, and 2)for a given power, say 200mW, the power is indeed *exact* 200mW for each voltage version.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting
The clue MAY be in their use of the term "4 different sensities". Pull in voltages vary from 4V on low sensitivity down to 3.5V on high sensitivity coil. You'd need some very special circuit constraints before this made much sense. 

Note that the UL contact ratings are 0.5A for the two low power  coils and 1A for the two high power coils 

Data sheet here works for me:http://www.tycoelectronics.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Specification+Or+Standard%7F108-98007%7FC%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_SS_108-98007_C.pdf